# TreeView items randomly appear under the wrong parent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, treeview, winui-3

**Edit 2:**
I'm replacing the original text of my question and references to my original code with a simpler example instead, per Peter Duniho's suggestion.

I'm developing a WinUI 3 app. The main window has a `TreeView`, with a hierarchy as follows: the top-level items are of type `CarMake`, and each `CarMake` can have 0 or more `CarModel` children. The window has an `ObservableCollection<CarMake>` property called `Cars` which is the source for the top level `CarMake`s, and each `CarMake` has an `ObservableCollection<CarModel>` property `CarModels` which is the source for its children in the `TreeView`.

Here's the XAML definitions for the `CarMakeView` and `CarModelView` types, respectively:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Padding="12"
            x:Class="Cars.View.CarMakeView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CarMake.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

</StackPanel>
```

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
    x:Class="Cars.View.CarModelView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=CarModel.Name}" />
    
</StackPanel>
```

`CarMake.cs` and `CarModel.cs`:

```cs
namespace Cars.Model
{
    public class CarMake
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Cars.Model
{
    public class CarModel
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the XAML for `MainWindow`.

```xml
<Window
<!-- imports etc. -->
>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
                        
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarMakeTemplate" x:DataType="model:CarMake">
                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind CarModels}">
                    <viewModel:CarMakeView CarMake="{Binding}"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarModelTemplate" x:DataType="model:CarModel">
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <viewModel:CarModelView CarModel="{Binding}"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <utility:CarItemSelector
                x:Key="CarItemSelector"
                CarMakeTemplate="{StaticResource CarMakeTemplate}"
                CarModelTemplate="{StaticResource CarModelTemplate}" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        
        
        <TextBlock/>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars}"  
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CarItemSelector}">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

And finally the code-behind for `MainWindow`. Note that I initialized the `Cars` property with a hard-coded collection of `CarMake`, each with associated `CarModel`s. This defines the data hierarchy that we *expect* to see represented in the UI:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<CarMake> Cars { get; set; } =
        new ()
        {
            new CarMake { Name = "Chevrolet", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "Camaro" }, new CarModel { Name = "Blazer" }, new CarModel { Name = "Beretta" } } },
            new CarMake { Name = "Land Rover", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "Discovery" }, new CarModel { Name = "LR3" }, new CarModel { Name = "Range Rover" } } },
            new CarMake { Name = "Quadra", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "Turbo-R 740" }, new CarModel { Name = "Type-66 Avenger" }} },
            new CarMake { Name = "Powell Motors", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "The Homer" }}}
        };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Here's what I expect**: in the UI, car models should appear within the visual children of the car make they were assigned to in code. So, for example, "The Homer", and only "The Homer", should ever appear in the children of "Powell Motors".

**Here's the problem**: after launching the app, and expanding and collapsing at least one of the car make items, car models start showing underneath the wrong car make. For example, "The Homer" car model might appear under "Chevrolet" instead of under "Powell Motors". Every time a top-level car make item is collapsed then expanded, a brand new set of car models appears underneath it, apparently randomly sourced from its neighbors. It's almost like the UI framework is just juggling the `CarModel`s around and sticking them under whichever `CarMake` it feels like, instead of respecting the hierarchy defined by the data.

**What I'd like to know**: what do I need to change so that car model names only appear under their assigned parent in the UI? Also, I'd like to understand what's causing this problem.

I know WinUI 3 is absolute bleeding edge right now so part of me hopes it's a bug in the framework and not something I've done. I tried to include all the code I thought was relevant to the issue, but in case the problem lies elsewhere [here's a link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/AJLeuer/Cars) - it's extremely minimal, only enough code to illustrate the problem, and takes only a couple seconds to build in Visual Studio.

Comment: The WinUI3 team is actively answering questions here: [WinUI3 issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues)

Comment: Thanks Roy. If the consensus is it's a bug with WinUI and not something I'm doing wrong I'll for sure open an issue there.

Comment: _"I'm so baffled by this that I don't even know where to begin when it comes to debugging it"_ -- step #1: create a [mcve]. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Read [ask] for more information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why this made the difference, but the solution turned out to be changing the `Mode` of `x:Bind` on the `CarModelView`'s `TextBlock` `Text` to be `OneWay`, instead of leaving it at its default which is apparently `OneTime`:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
    x:Class="Cars.View.CarModelView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=CarModel.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
    
</StackPanel>
```

**Edit**: As Peter Duniho pointed out below, Microsoft does document that `OneTime` is the default mode for `{x:Bind}` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension), though why `OneTime` caused specifically the bizarre behavior I observed remains a mystery to me. But in any event this at least seems to guarantee that the car names always appear exactly where they're expected, and never where they're not.

Comment: FWIW, I can't provide the official answer to why `OneTime` is the default, but in general, UWP bindings are designed to be lightweight, because the original intent (now all but abandoned as far as I can tell) was for UWP to be the primary API for phones and other lightweight devices. That's why there's also the `{x:Bind}` markup, vs WPF's original `{Binding}`. Indeed, I think you'll find that had you used `{Binding}` instead, you wouldn't have run into the problem; I think even in UWP, `{Binding}`'s default mode is still `OneWay` for `TextBlock`.

Comment: That does help make more sense of why `OneTime` is the default, even if just about any non-trivial use case for binding on a desktop app would probably want to use `OneWay`. You're right I probably should have stuck with `{Binding}`, but I did appreciate that `{x:Bind}` simplifies other things: not having to deal with `DataContext`, for example, something that never really made intuitive sense to me.

Comment: Oh, and as far as this being documented, it is. Very prominently: [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension): _"Tip: {x:Bind} has a default mode of OneTime, unlike {Binding}, which has a default mode of OneWay. This was chosen for performance reasons..."_

Comment: Ah, well fair enough then. And I appreciate that they gave their reasons, though if it's true what I've since read elsewhere, that UWP was designed to primarily accommodate the performance limitations of mobile devices, well I appreciate that quite a bit less.

Comment: But I'll update my answer anyway to reflect what you mentioned.

Comment: _"if it's true what I've since read elsewhere, that UWP was designed to primarily accommodate the performance limitations of mobile devices, well I appreciate that quite a bit less"_ -- yeah, me too. Frankly, the whole Silverlight/UWP thing disgusts me; a lot of infighting, API churn, and incompatibility occurred in the name of "lightweight", when it was entirely predictable that performance limits were merely temporary. And for what? No Windows API on modern mobile devices at all now. It was all a waste. :(